# Grabbing Destination Link of a Redirect

Tags: php, url

Hopefully I am just overlooking this.

I am trying to grab the destination URL of a redirect link using PHP. It's to get the site URL of an affiliate/cloaked link.

Best example:  http://tinyurl.com/2tx goes to google.com

NOTE: This is an example, the links are created dynamically

Right now I pass the URL through

www.mysite.com/redirect.php?link=http://tinyurl.com/2tx

Here is the code from the site - NOTE:  since the URL has Ampersands in them I had to go this route over GET.

```
<?php
    $name = http_build_query($_GET);
    // which you would then may want to strip away the first 'name='
    $name = substr($name, strlen('name='));
    //change link to a nice URL
    $url = rawurldecode($name);
?>
```

I have a simple script that grabs the URL, how could I process the URL to get the destination URL?

Hopefully that's not too confusing.

Cheers,
Robb

Comment: It is very confusing. Do you mean $_GET['link']?

Comment: I think is looking for a way to get "google.com" from the tinyurl link

Comment: this is what you need: http://zzz.rezo.net/HowTo-Expand-Short-URLs.html

Comment: I need to get the destination URL of the cloaked link. I added the code I am using. Sorry about that, very silly of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it (Read the comments):

```
<?php

// Connect to the page:
$ch = curl_init("http://tinyurl.com/2tx");

// Don't get the body (remove if you want the body):
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

// Follow the page redirects:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// Retun the data as a string (Remove to echo to the page):
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute:
curl_exec($ch);

// Get data:
print_r($data = curl_getinfo($ch));

// Get just the url:
echo $data["url"];
```

Comment: oohh this is good so far...question, how do I get rid of all the crap before the link is printed? You can see here: http://mediaortech.com/justme/redirect2.php

Comment: just replace this `print_r($data = curl_getinfo($ch));` with this `$data = curl_getinfo($ch);`

Comment: You my friend have nailed it - I should of seen that silly print_r

Answer (score 4):

You should post some of your code next time.  I assume you are using `cURL` to do this.  It's fairly simple:

```
//sanitize
$ch = curl_init($_GET['link']);

//follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_exec($ch);

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

EDIT: per Dagon, you just want to "know the url but not go there."  It is more efficient to use this setting if you only need to know the url but not get its contents:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Comment: @Dagon I thought that he wanted to get the destination URL

Comment: i though he wanted to know the url but not go there - well one of us is right :-)

Comment: Funny...you are actually both right...my step two was to actually go to the link.  But I need the link first to share on Facebook.  The cloaked links don't share on Facebook well, so I am going to pass through the destination link (why I need it first) then on share they are redirected.

Comment: i demand (JK) half the rep points, when you select this answer :-)

Comment: @ExplosionPills the issue here is the link has Ampersands in it vital to the Affiliate link so GET doesn't work

Comment: @synergy989 that sounds like a separate issue to me .. *which* link has Ampersands?  When does it come into play?

Comment: http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=USXdsD0kQ9I&offerid=251379.10001421&type=3&subid=0

When I use get it returns:

http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=USXdsD0kQ9I

Comment: if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
$link = $_GET['link'];
}
or using your script, I only get the first half of the URL and miss everything after the Ampersand

Comment: @synergy989 where is the link to your page displayed?  You need to encode the `&` in that URL

Comment: you will want to add this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` otherwise it will display it all on the page.

Comment: @ExplosionPills but the URLS are dynamically created, can I encode them?  som have Ampersands, some don't... he is how I had the script before, you can see it's not grabbing the whole URL: http://mediaortech.com/stack/redirect1.php?link=http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=USXdsD0kQ9I&offerid=251379.10001421&type=3&subid=0

Comment: @synergy989 dynamically created by who?  If you control how the URLs are created, simply encode them before you create the request to `?link=`

Comment: @ExplosionPills the links are added on the front end of a website.  Some are affiliate links some aren't...they are added by users so I can't go and manually encode every single one that comes through. Does that make sense?

Comment: @synergy989 no, not really .. you should encode them if you can.  Anyway, it is an interesting conundrum.  Perhaps you could try `$url = end(explode('link=', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));`

Comment: @ExplosionPills you've actually got it right, the issue is grabbing the URL which I can do via http_build_query (in my script above), then pass it through...you can see Ryan Naddy's answer which is built of yours.  Question - how do I give you both rep?

Comment: @synergy989 I'm not in love with his answer, although it is accurate.  You can give rep by upvoting.  If you want to accept an answer, accept whichever one you feel helped you the most or will be most helpful for visitors in the future.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20591/discussion-between-synergy989-and-explosion-pills)

Answer (score 0):

Make a HTTP HEAD Request to the URL you have. You will get back an HTTP 301 or 302 response with the destination URL.

Example: Put your URL [here](http://web-sniffer.net/) to see the response returned when making an HTTP Head Request.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an encoding issue. The parameter in your URL is not encoded, so it's probably damaged when trying to get it using $_GET.

You want to use this URL:

```
www.mysite.com/redirect.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2tx
```

You can encode URL variables in PHP using the `urlencode()` function. The variable that (I think) you want can now be accessed like this:

```
echo $_GET['link'];  // http://tinyurl.com/2tx
```

Comment: I edited to reflect this but the links are created dynamically so I can't hard code them :(

Comment: The link is passed to your page in the URL right? Like, if someone wanted to peek ahead at `http://goo.gl/ytVLg` then someone would go to `http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FytVLg`    ?

Comment: yes but is there a way to code them dynamically?  Basically someone comes and types in: wwww.mysite.com/redirect.php?link=LINKHERE  I personally can't encode the link so is there a way to do that via PHP?